# How to initialize firebaseui widget with AngularFireAuth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebaseui

I have a constructor in my LoginComponent

```
ui!: firebaseui.auth.AuthUI;


constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {

}
ngOnInit() {
     this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.auth); // this line getting error
}
```

I can not pass `this.auth.auth` in AuthUI because angular-fire removed `auth` it on its latest version.
[github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2409)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: this.auth has no property "apikey"